# Изменение/добавление содержимого на активной вкладке в Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как изменить содержимое на активной вкладке в Chrome с помощью расширения? Разрешение к работе со вкладками получено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab

Краткий пересказ.

В *manifest.json* в разделе **permission** прописываете **activeTab**.

Далее в разделе **background** прописываем скрипт который должен будет выполниться.

И в принципе все.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
    });
});
```

Т.е по клику на иконку расширения(browser action) будет выполнен код (в текущей вкладке), который был передан **executeScript** в качестве параметра.

Тут в **executeScript** передается готовая строка кода, но можно просто передать имя файла, который затем будет встроен в страницу.
За остальной информацией по функции обратитесь к [документации](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

Все остальное зависит от вашей задумки того когда/что должно сработать.

Можно и с **chrome.tabs.onActivated** попробовать поиграть или еще каким предлогаемым функционалом.

Comment: а как выполнить код не при клике, а сразу? можно на определенном сайта